# Best way to get current year minus 5 years

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, date

I'm actually have the next query that I use to obtain the current year minus 5 years in january in this format 'YYYYMM'.

```
select TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YEAR'),12*5*-1),'YYYYMM') from dual;
```

I want to know if this way is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve the goal.

```
SQL> select to_char(trunc(add_months(sysdate,-12*5),'YEAR'),'YYYYMM') from dual;
```

OR

```
SQL>  select to_char(trunc(SYSDATE - interval '5' year,'YEAR'),'YYYYMM') from dual;
```

Regarding the second one, what happens if the SYSDATE or the current date supplied happens to be a leap day?

```
SQL> select to_char(trunc(to_Date('2016-02-29','YYYY-MM-DD') - interval '5' year,'YEAR'),'YYYYMM') 
    from dual;
select to_char(trunc(to_Date('2016-02-29','YYYY-MM-DD') - interval '5' year,'YEAR'),'YYYYMM') 
from dual
                                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
```

What happens if we use the first method?

```
SQL> select to_char(trunc(add_months(to_Date('2016-02-29','YYYY-MM-DD'),-12*5),'YEAR'),'YYYYMM') 
     from dual;

TO_CHA
------
201101
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL>

```
select trunc(sysdate)AS TODAY,
2  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 12 * 5 * -1) AS minus_5_year from dual;
```

Result:

```
TODAY       MINUS_5_YEAR
----------- ------------
04/03/2021  04/03/2016
```

### **for leap day**

SQL>

```
select to_date('29/02/2020')AS TODAY,
  2  ADD_MONTHS(to_date('29/02/2020'), 12 * 5 * -1) AS minus_5_year from dual;
```

Result:

```
TODAY       MINUS_5_YEAR
----------- ------------
29/02/2020  28/02/2015
```